# How can I represent combined PK in a EER Diagram?

Tags: entity-relationship

In my sample I'm trying to:

- limit events to occur only once a day.

[image: EER DIAGRAM]

Comment: Do you mean each event can only occur once a day, or only one event can occur each day?

Comment: @reaanb each event can olny occure once a day - thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you meant each event can only occur once a day, I would use one of the following two approaches:

1. Change `time` into an attribute of `occurrence`, so that the latter is a relationship determined by `event` and `date`.
2. Change `occurrence` into a weak entity dependent on `event`, with `date` as a weak key and `time` a normal attribute.

The difference here is whether you consider `date` to be an entity set or a value set.

[image: Event-Occurrence ER diagram]

This nicely demonstrates the complexity of the entity-relationship model vs plain relational modeling. Both diagrams above express the functional dependency `(event, date) -> time`, for which we just need a table `occurrence (eventid PK, date PK, time)`. The extra semantics introduced by the ER model have no value on the logical or physical levels.